# I can't find my items after I die

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I die in Minecraft, I go back my point of death about 20 secounds later, but my items aren't there, why is this?

It can't be because I arrived there too late and they despawned, so I think it's because of some setting. I however, don't know how to change it back to normal.

Comment: Are you in survival single player, or on a server?

Comment: Close voters, please remember that a close vote is not a super downvote. This question isn't even that unclear.

Comment: no i'm not on a server and no one could pick them up but it does not matter because I just had a setting on that items don't drop but now i fixed it and they decided to drop

Answer (score 8):

There might be 4 reasons of this.

**Someone is picking them up.** If you are playing on a server, this is much more likely. Even if you are playing solo, some mobs can pick up items.

**They are being destroyed.** This depends on how you die. If you fell into lava, your items will probably drop there too, after they pop off when you die, and be destroyed. [Minecraft Wiki's Item Page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_%28entity%29) gives examples of explosions, fire, lava, a falling anvil, and contact with cactus.

**Your game client is bugged.** Can you be playing on an old version, a snapshot or using mods? They might cause it.

**Server Plugins might be removing them.**, but this only happens if you are on a server. Only thing you can do to this is not dying, or contacting admins to remove this feature.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Ave's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/256996):

When dying by suffocation, for example by teleporting into a solid block, will cause items to occupy a nearby empty space. This can even be much lower or much higher than where you died.

When on the "game over" screen, the world does not freeze. This means that any item timers will still be running when on that screen. I believe entities will not appear despawned on that screen, but they will despawn regardless.

Answer (score -1):

It maybe be if you are on a server that they have a ground item clear. I have been on many that do that in like factions so check out there rules and stuff to see if they have that in place.

Comment: -1 There are 2 existing answers. Another reason is that there are more possible ways.

Comment: was just giving one example.

Comment: You're supposed to explain about the possibilities. It's like youre saying, "Try this! It worked for me!" yeah it works for you but maybe not the others. Say something like "I have tried using this and it works.If that doesn't help, try doing this" That's okay. Don't worry I'm not arguing. That's why you got downvoted, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: Im sorry i will try to do that more often just trying to help with possible reasons why so he?she is not as confused as why this has happened thats for your feedback i will try some changes an i have you take away the demotion.

Comment: Ok I understand.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the ways they could disappear and I got ideas [from Ave](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/256996):

1. They despawn. You're correct about that. I died before and retrieved my items, but not all of them. Dropped items could despawn if they aren't taken for a long time.
2. Someone else picked it up. If you're playing multiplayer, like in a server, someone else could've collected them. Try to ask whoever found a bunch of your dropped items in chat.
3. They were burnt. Did you fall in lava? Lava could destroy dropped items and you can lose them forever. Cacti can also destroy them.
4. Servers remove it. If you're on a server, they might remove any dropped items not in use.
5. You probably checked the wrong place. There are many places where you could've died. Check those areas.
6. A random bug. Though not known worldwide, sometimes the game could be bugged out and they could disappear. Chunks that are bugged too, since they can load up areas. It may also because of memory too.

Answer (score -2):

Your question isn't very clear. If you have any command blocks running in your world, they might be removing items, or the items could just be despawning.

Comment: If there were command blocks, there could've been a message saying the command has been used, but there was no message. -1

Comment: What he was asking was clear, he just didn't tell us very much.